# ANSIBLE doesn't work - syntax check

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm trying to setup on ansible my first playbooks. 
Hovever... no matter which example I'm trying to test.. i receive similar error:

```
"xyz is not a valid attribute for a Play"
```

For example:

```
 $ cat a2.yml
- name: Update and upgrade
  become: true
  apt:
    upgrade: yes
    update_cache: yes


$ ansible-playbook a2.yml --syntax-check
ERROR! 'apt' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in '/home/pi/My/ansible/a2.yml': line 1, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Update and upgrade
  ^ here
```

Whats wrong?

PS.

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.4.2.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/pi/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08) [GCC 6.3.0 20170124]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running the Following Playbook syntax appears to be correct but getting following ERROR!- 'blockinfile' is not a valid attribute for a Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468870/running-the-following-playbook-syntax-appears-to-be-correct-but-getting-followin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Playbooks Intro](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_intro.html) documentation.
Your entry should be a `task` item.

```
---
- hosts: ...
  tasks:
    - name: Update and upgrade
      become: true
      apt:
        upgrade: yes
        update_cache: yes
```

Comment: Works ;-)
I didn't realize that "tasks" is mandatory. (whole concept was bit unclear for me).
Thank for help.